# #+NAME: in a property drawer

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to be able to add a `#+NAME` to a property drawer that would name a code block thats split between sub org headers. Im at loss on how this is done?

this is a current example of a tmux conf thats split with different org sub headers:

```
 * tmux conf
 :PROPERTIES:
 :header-args: :noweb yes  :tangle /zeltak@132.72.155.204:~/.tmux.conf
 :END:



***** Mouse  
      :PROPERTIES:
      :ID:       ba8ce7aa-2b3b-43be-816d-ea2ab515a999
      :END:
#+BEGIN_SRC conf 
#-------------->  mouse
setw -g mouse on
set-option -g status-keys vi
#+END_SRC

***** Theme and look
      :PROPERTIES:
      :ID:       85257f51-1306-4caf-a055-a6df3afac1a5
      :END:
#+BEGIN_SRC conf 
#--------------> THEME AND LOOK
#default theme picker
source /home/zeltak/.tmux/neonB
#source /home/zeltak/.tmux/solarized-dark
#+END_SRC
```

I want to add a name (`#+NAME`) for all the sub headers that will make '.tmux.conf'. anyone know how thats done?

Answer (score 2):

Ok found the answer hidden away in a org manual page 
the answer it so to use ':noweb-ref NAME' as an argument in the drawer

so like this in the above example

```
    * tmux conf
 :PROPERTIES:
 :header-args: :tangle ~/.tmux.conf :noweb-ref tmux.conf
 :END:



***** Mouse  
      :PROPERTIES:
      :ID:       ba8ce7aa-2b3b-43be-816d-ea2ab515a999
      :END:
#+BEGIN_SRC conf 
#-------------->  mouse
setw -g mouse on
set-option -g status-keys vi
#+END_SRC

***** Theme and look
      :PROPERTIES:
      :ID:       85257f51-1306-4caf-a055-a6df3afac1a5
      :END:
#+BEGIN_SRC conf 
#--------------> THEME AND LOOK
#default theme picker
source /home/zeltak/.tmux/neonB
#source /home/zeltak/.tmux/solarized-dark
#+END_SRC
```